# How to type function calls when using Function.prototype.apply

Tags: javascript, typescript, types

I have the following types:

```
type Options = 'A' | 'B' | 'C' | 'D'

type SpecificOptions = 'A' | 'B'

type OptionsValueType = {
  A: () => void,
  B: string
}
```

I use those to build the following class methods:

```
declare class MyClass {
  myFunction(option: 'A', value: OptionsValueType['A'])
  myFunction(option: 'B', value: OptionsValueType['B'])
  myFunction(option: Exclude<Options, SpecificOptions>, value: number)

}
```

This works great:
[image]

And I also have some code that calls `myFunction` inside a loop, using `Function.prototype.apply`, it looks something like this:

```
const calls = [
  ['A', 1],
  ['B', 1],
  ['C', 1],
]

for (const call of calls) {
  a.myFunction.apply(undefined, call)
}
```

But the code above does not shows any type error.

I cannot use `as const` on the `calls` array because it's built dynamically (and even if I could, it does not seems to work either).

How to type the code above to make sure the `.apply` is correctly typed?  Or is that currently not possible with Typescript?

Above code is available on [this Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=type%20Options%20%3D%20'A'%20%7C%20'B'%20%7C%20'C'%20%7C%20'D'%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20SpecificOptions%20%3D%20'A'%20%7C%20'B'%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20OptionsValueType%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20A%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20void%2C%0D%0A%20%20B%3A%20string%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Adeclare%20class%20MyClass%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20myFunction(option%3A%20'A'%2C%20value%3A%20OptionsValueType%5B'A'%5D)%0D%0A%20%20myFunction(option%3A%20'B'%2C%20value%3A%20OptionsValueType%5B'B'%5D)%0D%0A%20%20myFunction(option%3A%20Exclude%3COptions%2C%20SpecificOptions%3E%2C%20value%3A%20number)%0D%0A%20%20%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0Adeclare%20var%20a%3A%20MyClass%0D%0A%0D%0Aa.myFunction('A'%2C%20()%20%3D%3E%20%7B%20%7D)%0D%0Aa.myFunction('B'%2C%20'')%0D%0Aa.myFunction('C'%2C%201)%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20calls%20%3D%20%5B%0D%0A%20%20%5B'A'%2C%201%5D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%5B'B'%2C%201%5D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%5B'C'%2C%201%5D%2C%0D%0A%5D%0D%0A%0D%0Afor%20(const%20call%20of%20calls)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%2F%2F%20%40TODO%20Correctly%20type%20each%20arg%20pair%2C%20it%20should%20be%20throwing%20an%20error%20here.%0D%0A%20%20a.myFunction.apply(undefined%2C%20call)%0D%0A%7D)

Comment: I am not sure I understand the question given `value: number` and the `'1'` string being passed therein.

Comment: "*it's built dynamically*" - so you expect a runtime error depending on the passed values, not a static compiler error?

Answer (score 1):

If `calls` is built dynamically then no, there is no way to get a compile time error based on its value.

You can check the values at runtime and throw an error of your own.  Otherwise, JS will pass them in as function arguments regardless of their type.

If you wanted to check the types yourself you could do:

```
for (const call of calls) {
  if (typeof call[0] !== 'string' || typeof call[1] !== 'string') {
    throw new Error('Both arguments to myFunction must be strings');
  }
  a.myFunction.apply(undefined, call)
}
```